# What is the use of uploadPermissions() method in azure java sdk (v8.3.0) for blob storage

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-sdk, azure-java-sdk

Azure-java-sdk:8:3:0

I can not understand complete the uses of uploadPermissions() method (below is the signature of method).
(com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.CloudBlobContainer#uploadPermissions()) 
This method uploads two thing

1. BlobContainerPublicAccessType  (OFF | BLOB| CONTAINER)
2. HashMap ==> sharedAccessBlobPolicyMap

I can understand the first thing that will be used to change the public access level of the container but unable to understand the 2nd thing (sharedAccessBlobPolicyMap ) that when the sharedAccessBlobPolicyMap will be used?

As per my understanding in Azure, blob policy is used while generating Shared Access Signature. Is there any other use of blob policy?

```
/**
     * Uploads the container's permissions using the specified request options and operation context.
     * 
     * @param permissions
     *            A {@link BlobContainerPermissions} object that represents the permissions to upload.
     * @param accessCondition
     *            An {@link AccessCondition} object that represents the access conditions for the container.
     * @param options
     *            A {@link BlobRequestOptions} object that specifies any additional options for the request. Specifying
     *            <code>null</code> will use the default request options from the associated service client (
     *            {@link CloudBlobClient}).
     * @param opContext
     *            An {@link OperationContext} object that represents the context for the current operation. This object
     *            is used to track requests to the storage service, and to provide additional runtime information about
     *            the operation.
     * 
     * @throws StorageException
     *             If a storage service error occurred.
     */
    @DoesServiceRequest
    public void uploadPermissions(final BlobContainerPermissions permissions, final AccessCondition accessCondition,
            BlobRequestOptions options, OperationContext opContext) throws StorageException
```

Comment: Regarding sharedAccessBlobPolicyMap, it is used to set Azure blob share access policy. The policy specifies the start time, expiry time, and permissions for a shared access signature. Regarding shared access signature, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/delegate-access-with-shared-access-signature

Comment: sharedAccessBlobPolicyMap contains an alias for every policy but java API to create SAS doesn't take any rathe it takes policy object again then what is the use of that alias.

Comment: The alias is the policy name.

Comment: Do you have any other concerns?

Comment: while generating sas it is taking "SharedAccessBlobPolicy" again not taking any alias (policyName) then where this alias will be used?

Comment: To make me better understand your issue, could you please provide the code you use. Regarding how to use the method ```uploadPermissions```, please refer to https://github.com/Azure-Samples/storage-blob-java-getting-started/blob/cc3c3d48e7e32f37bca408e3090fdf975b3a76ee/src/BlobAdvanced.java#L267

Comment: @JimXu Please summarize your inputs as an answer below so it helps others in the community. Thanks!